# Calling 3rd party Lib functions in React

Tags: javascript, d3.js, reactjs

I'm using d3 with React and have some d3 related functions that need access to a few d3 variables / objects. I need to call one these functions when componentWillReceiveProps() is called. I provided a minimal example bellow, the comments are whats most important.

```
class App extends Component {
   constructor() {
      super();
   }

   shouldComponentUpdate() {
      return false;
   }

   componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
      /* Need to call reset() here */
   }

   componentDidMount() {
       let svg = d3.select(this.refs.map).append('svg')
            .attr('width', width)
            .attr('height', height);

       let g = svg.append('g')
            .style('stroke-width', '.4px');

       function reset() {
          /* needs access to g */
          g.transition()
                .duration(1500)
                .style('stroke-width', '.4px')
                .attr('transform', '');
       }
   }

   render() {
        return (
            <div id="map" ref="map"></div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Define `reset()` function as component method
- Bind `this` reference to the `reset()` function
- use `this.g` to get the value of g to use it across different component methods.

**Sample Code:**

```js
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
      super();
      this.reset = this.reset.bind(this)
    }

    shouldComponentUpdate() {
      return false;
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
      this.reset();
    }

    componentDidMount() {
      let svg = d3.select(this.refs.map).append('svg')
        .attr('width', '100px')
        .attr('height', '100px');


      // Assigning value to `this.g` to be able use it in other methods.
      this.g = svg.append("circle")
        .attr("cx", 25)
        .attr("cy", 25)
        .attr("r", 25)
        .style("fill", "purple");
    }

    reset() {
      // After component will be mounted, you would have needed value in `this.g`.
      this.g.transition()
        .duration(1500)
        .style("fill", "red");
    }

    render() {
        return ( < div >
          < div id = "map"
          ref = "map" > < /div>
      <button onClick={this.reset}>Reset</button >
          < /div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App / > , document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should define `reset` function as component method and in `componentDidMount` callback, instead of assigning value to local `g` variable, you should assign it to `this.g`:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  shouldComponentUpdate() {
    return false;
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    this.reset();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    let svg = d3.select(this.refs.map).append('svg')
      .attr('width', width)
      .attr('height', height);

    // Assigning value to `this.g` to be able use it in other methods.
    this.g = svg.append('g')
      .style('stroke-width', '.4px');
  }

  reset() {
    // After component will be mounted, you would have needed value in `this.g`.
    this.g.transition()
      .duration(1500)
      .style('stroke-width', '.4px')
      .attr('transform', '');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div id="map" ref="map"></div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: don't we need to declare `this.g` with the initial value in constructor like `this.g = null' ?

Comment: @GaleelBhasha, we can, to make code more self-documented, but  it's not necessary. After component will be mounted we will assign to `this.g` some value. `componentWillReceiveProps` function can't be called before `componentWillMount`, so when we call reset, `this.g` won't be undefined.

Comment: do we need to bind the 'this' reference to the `reset` ? In this example - https://jsbin.com/lozelarure/edit?js,output 

When I click the reset button I am getting the following error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'transition' of undefined`

To add 'this' reference, If I modify the `reset()` declaration to `reset = () => {}` or add `this.reset = this.reset.bind(this)` at constructor, that works for me.In the demo I am invoking the 'reset' from the `render()` method. I hope this will be same when 'reset' is called from `componentWillReceiveProps()` - is my assumption right?

Comment: @GaleelBhasha your example is a lot better then mine,  I'd change it to what you have if 1evens answer was not referencing it. Also any suggestions for rephrasing the question?

Comment: @Groovietunes, sure, if you are providing component method as callback to element, you should use `.bind(this)`, to be able access to `this` reference from this function.